# Equation for fitting exponential Decay model in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, equation, curve

I have a data set, (x and y) that I need to fit with an analytical model in scipy.

[image]

I have tried using the MATLAB curve fitting toolbox and a few other tools, including simply adding terms to standard fitting equations (e.g. exponential).

My only real constraint is that I would like to limit the number of parameters that need to be fitted, 4 would be ideal, but 6 could work and I am somewhat sensitive to a model that fits the data set above the linear portion of the curve at the beginning. This is why I don't like the polynominal fitting solutions I have been able to get.

Here is the data for referencs,

```
Y = np.array([7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.50E-01 , 7.49E-01 , 7.49E-01 , 7.49E-01 , 7.49E-01 , 7.49E-01 , 7.48E-01 , 7.48E-01 , 7.48E-01 , 7.47E-01 , 7.47E-01 , 7.46E-01 , 7.46E-01 , 7.45E-01 , 7.44E-01 , 7.44E-01 , 7.43E-01 , 7.42E-01 , 7.41E-01 , 7.40E-01 , 7.39E-01 , 7.38E-01 , 7.37E-01 , 7.36E-01 , 7.35E-01 , 7.34E-01 , 7.32E-01 , 7.31E-01 , 7.30E-01 , 7.28E-01 , 7.27E-01 , 7.25E-01 , 7.24E-01 , 7.22E-01 , 7.21E-01 , 7.19E-01 , 7.17E-01 , 7.16E-01 , 7.14E-01 , 7.12E-01 , 7.10E-01 , 7.08E-01 , 7.06E-01 , 7.04E-01 , 7.02E-01 , 7.00E-01 , 6.98E-01 , 6.96E-01 , 6.94E-01 , 6.92E-01 , 6.90E-01 , 6.88E-01 , 6.86E-01 , 6.83E-01 , 6.81E-01 , 6.79E-01 , 6.77E-01 , 6.75E-01 , 6.72E-01 , 6.70E-01 , 6.68E-01 , 6.65E-01 , 6.63E-01 , 6.61E-01 , 6.58E-01 , 6.56E-01 , 6.54E-01 , 6.51E-01 , 6.49E-01 , 6.46E-01 , 6.44E-01 , 6.42E-01 , 6.39E-01 , 6.37E-01 , 6.34E-01 , 6.32E-01 , 6.30E-01 , 6.27E-01 , 6.25E-01 , 6.22E-01 , 6.20E-01 , 6.17E-01 , 6.15E-01 , 6.12E-01 , 6.10E-01 , 6.08E-01 , 6.05E-01 , 6.03E-01 , 6.00E-01 , 5.98E-01 , 5.95E-01 , 5.93E-01 , 5.91E-01 , 5.88E-01 , 5.86E-01 , 5.83E-01 , 5.81E-01 , 5.79E-01 , 5.76E-01 , 5.74E-01 , 5.71E-01 , 5.69E-01 , 5.67E-01 , 5.64E-01 , 5.62E-01 , 5.60E-01 , 5.57E-01 , 5.55E-01 , 5.53E-01 , 5.50E-01 , 5.48E-01 , 5.46E-01 , 5.43E-01 , 5.41E-01 , 5.39E-01 , 5.36E-01 , 5.34E-01 , 5.32E-01 , 5.29E-01 , 5.27E-01 , 5.25E-01])
X = np.arange(len(Y))
```

Lastly, I am using symfit but I am open to using scipy.optimize.curve_fit or other methods if it helps to solve my problem.

Comment: The data do not correspond to the figure

Comment: @Stelios, Yes it has been corrected now. Sorry that took so long, my internet died so I had to set up a hotspot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt to fit your data with a three-parameter function `f`. Note that the function is undefined at `x=0`. However, scipy does manage to provide a reasonable fit for all other points. You may want to replace `x` in `f` with something like `x+very_small_number` to obtain a function that is valid for `x=0`.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * (1 - np.exp(-c/x))

sol = curve_fit(f, X, Y, p0 = (.75,.75,200,) )

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', label = 'data')
plt.plot(X, [f(x,*sol[0]) for x in X], lw = 3, label = 'fit')
```

[image]